# How can I fill image in scroll view to fill screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am playing around with scroll views, and I've run into an issue I'be stuck with. I have a view controller create in Storyboard. The view controller contains a scroll view which fills the entire superview.

I then added the images programmatically to the scroll view. The images do show within the scroll view and paging works just fine. Only problem is the scroll view is set ti fill superview but the image view that hold the images seems like it stops above where the navigation bar would be. How can I have the image view fill the whole view within the scroll view?

```swift
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet weak var pagingView: UIPageControl!
  var images = [UIImage]()
  var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 0,height: 0)



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true 

        images = [UIImage(named: "Slide1")!, UIImage(named: "Slide2")!, UIImage(named: "Slide3")!, UIImage(named: "Slide4")!]

        pagingView.numberOfPages = images.count

// This is where I think I'm having the height problem. 
        for i in 0..<images.count {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            let x = self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)

            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.image = images[i]

            scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i + 1)

            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }

    }




    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width

        pagingView.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
```

After setting nav bar to hidden, here is the output

Scroll view background color is red

[image]

Comment: can you post you the result image?

Comment: @Harish Yes of course

Comment: so you want to see the image whole screen? which means you don't want to see the navigation bar?

Comment: One obvious problem: `viewDidLoad` is too early. You do not know at that time what `self.view.frame` will be when things get going. Please read http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/. — Another problem of course is that you are saying `frame` when you mean `bounds`.

Comment: @Harish Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @matt Thanks for taking the time to share that resource with me. I will dabble in it now.

Comment: try to add some background color to scrollview and show the exact position of scrollview.

Comment: @Harish the scroll view background color is set to black. That top black view is the scroll view.

Comment: @Clint you may need to hide the navBar in this case, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case you need to enable the parent view clipsToBounds. Set `UIScrollview` `clipsToBounds` property to True.

Programmatically `scrollView.clipsToBounds = true`

In `UIStoryBoard` - Click the view->Attributes Inspector

If you would like to see the whole screen, make sure to add the `topConstraint` of `scrollView` assigned `superView` and hide the `navigationBar` in `viewWillAppear`,

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }
```

1. Make sure to remove the status bar by

   ```
   override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
      return true
   }
   ```
2. Update the Y position of Image.

   ```
   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: **self.scrollView.frame.minY**, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
   ```
3. Update the `scrollView` topConstraint by -20.

Comment: Hi Harish, thank you for your response. I already had clipsToBounds set in the storyboard

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, after setting nav bar to hidden, the image view gets closer to filling the view but now its just above the status bar. I changed the scroll view color to red so you can see it better. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Clint : check now.

Comment: Happy that you got result. Hope you upvote and accept the answer @Clint.