# How do i show current location on map?

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

In my code I am trying to access a users current location and show it on the map. I am currently getting a fatal error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` The error is inside `ViewDidLoad`.  What is the proper way to do so? I have all 3 of the correct privacy location *Always and when in use, when in use usage description , always usage description *

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit
    import CoreLocation

    class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        private var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
        private var currentLocation: CLLocation?

        //let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        //var currentLocation: CLLocation!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()//This where the fatal error appears

                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()////This where the fatal error appears

                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
            mapView.delegate = self
            mapView.mapType = .standard
            mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
            mapView.isScrollEnabled = true

            let leftMargin:CGFloat = 10
            let topMargin:CGFloat = 60
            let mapWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
            let mapHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width

            mapView.frame = CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: mapWidth, height: mapHeight)

            view.addSubview(mapView)


            if let coor = mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate{
                mapView.setCenter(coor, animated: true)
            }


        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            defer { currentLocation = locations.last }

            if currentLocation == nil {
                // Zoom to user location
                if let userLocation = locations.last {
                    let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 2000, longitudinalMeters: 2000)
                    mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
                }
            }

        }
        func checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = nil) {
            switch (authorizationStatus ?? CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            case .restricted, .denied:
                // show alert instructing how to turn on permissions
                print("Location Servies: Denied / Restricted")
            case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and  `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` to `locationManager` before creating an Instance will crash the application.

Update the code like below,

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make the `mapView` fill the whole screen?

Comment: You want to show above the status bar and navigation bar? if yes, check my answer here to whole screen. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60532597/1244403